# Url rewrite to lower case not working

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I have the following rewrite rules in my web.config. The canonical rule works, however the lower case rule doesn't.

I'm trying to test it like this: www.mysite.com/UPPERCASE. I would have expected the url to be transformed to www.mysite.com/uppercase, but it stays in uppercase. What am I doing wrong?

```
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="CanonicalHostName">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.mysite.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{MapSSL:{HTTPS}}www.mysite.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapSSL" defaultValue="OFF">
      <add key="ON" value="https://" />
      <add key="OFF" value="http://" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `patternSyntax="ExactMatch"` from the rule `LowerCaseRule` because in your case, you want to use the regular expression system (which comes by default or by setting `patternSyntax="ECMAScript"`).

So your rule should be:

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule">
  <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}"/>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was better for me. I noticed `{URL}` does not properly resolve when you have a path like `cassete.axd/scripts/myscript.js?xxx`, it will redirect to `cassette.axd?xxx` instead.

```
    <rule name="LowerCaseRule - HTTPS">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{ToLower:{HTTP_HOST}}{ToLower:{PATH_INFO}}" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="LowerCaseRule - HTTP">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{ToLower:{HTTP_HOST}}{ToLower:{PATH_INFO}}" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
```

Hope this helps someone.